# I want to get both Google reviews (comments) and star rating. How can I get them?

Tags: google-api

***Is there any API to get this and apply it on your application?***

Comment: Please follow our [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) with regards to asking questions. A good way to improve this post is to include more details about your objective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google My Business API has these feature.

To list review, you have two options that is to specify or list all. Here's an HTTP sample that you can use with cURL or Postman:

List all reviews:

```
GET https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{accountId}/locations/{locationId}/reviews
```

Get a specific review:

```
GET https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{accountId}/locations/{locationId}/reviews/{reviewId}
```

Here's an overview for [star rating](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.reviews#starrating).

If you want wish to implement this API on your application, you may refer to the [samples](https://github.com/google/google-my-business-samples) on how to use the client library.